# Appending many tables from many databases together in Access 2007

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I've tried to do some research on this, but am not finding anything useful (but it may just be that I am new to Access and am not looking for the right thing - if anyone has any links that answer my question, I am happy to be pointed in the right direction!) I have 5 Access 2007 databases that I have inherited. One of the agencies my company contracts with exported their information to us by creating a separate database for each year. Each DB has around 30 tables, with the same name across each year (i.e. each year has tables named “table a,” “table b,” etc.)

I am trying to create a singular database that has the same table structure ("table a," "table b," etc.) where each table has the combined information from each of the separate years. I know how to append tables, but I'm wondering if there's a quicker way to do it than doing each tables separately (i.e. appending the 2010 "table a" to the 2011 "table a," then appending the 2012 "table a," then 2013, and so on, for each of the 30 tables in each DB). Another agency imported their info to us in the same way (by year), but used XML files instead of Access. When I imported them into Access, I was given the option to append to existing tables, but I don't appear to be able to do the same when importing Access databases.

Thanks for the help. I'm relatively new to Access and SQL, so I apologize in advance if any of this was unclear or incorrect, and I’m happy to clarify anything that’s unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UNION query to do this. Unfortunately, you have to write the SQL out by hand because Access can't visualize a UNION in it's query editor.

This would look like:

```
SELECT 2015 as Year, field1, field2, field3, ... fieldN FROM TableA2015
UNION ALL
SELECT 2016 as Year, field1, field2, field3, ... fieldN FROM TableA2016
UNION ALL 
...
```

Essentially this is like stacking the results on top of each other, so it's important that all the fields line up in each `SELECT` statement.